# Creating List<Object> inside map

Tags: java-8

I have string like:

```
String input = "1 2 20\n"
        + "1 3 50\n"
        + "1 4 40\n"
        + "1 5 30\n"
        + "2 3 20\n"
        + "2 4 40\n"
        + "2 5 30\n"
        + "3 4 50\n"
        + "3 5 60\n"
        + "4 5 70\n";

  }
```

My Nodes Class:

```
class Nodes{
Integer from;
Integer to;
Integer cost;
}
```

Corresponding to each `String input` i want a Nodes object.

SO far I have been able to do like:

```
 List<Nodes> collect = new ArrayList<>();
```

**for loop starts here until the inputs are exhausted.**

```
    String[] s = Arrays.stream("1 3 50".split(" ")).toArray(String[]::new);
    Nodes nodes = new Nodes(Integer.valueOf(s[0]),Integer.valueOf(s[1]),Integer.valueOf(s[2]));
collect.add(nodes);
```

**for loop ends here**
**Required output :**

```
List<Nodes>
```

Is there a way so that I can create a `List` of `Nodes` inside stream only like `map(h->new Nodes(h[0],h[1],h[2]))`and at last collect it using `Collectors.toList()` so that i have `List<Nodes>`.

Comment: `List<Nodes> nodes = Arrays.stream(input.split("\\n"))
                .map(s->s.split("\\s"))
                .map(arr->new Nodes(Integer.valueOf(arr[0]),Integer.valueOf(arr[1]),Integer.valueOf(arr[2])))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
List<Nodes> nodes = Arrays.stream(input.split("\\n"))
            .map(s->s.split("\\s"))
            .map(arr->new Nodes(Integer.valueOf(arr[0]),Integer.valueOf(arr[1]),
                                Integer.valueOf(arr[2])))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make some modifications to your Nodes class first. Including some error handling in case there is something else than `ints` in your `String`. Then stream and collect:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StackOverflowTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "1 2 20\n"
            + "1 3 50\n"
            + "1 4 40\n"
            + "1 5 30\n"
            + "2 3 20\n"
            + "2 4 40\n"
            + "2 5 30\n"
            + "3 4 50\n"
            + "3 5 60\n"
            + "4 5 70\n";

    List<Nodes> list =
      input.lines()                              // streaming each line
           .map(s -> new Nodes(s.split(" ")))    // creating Nodes
           .collect(Collectors.toList());        // Collecting to List

    System.out.println(list);

  }
}

class Nodes{
  Integer from;
  Integer to;
  Integer cost;

  Nodes(String[] strings) {
    this(stringToInts(strings));     // avoid throwing error in constructor
  }

  Nodes(int[] ints) {
    this.from = ints[0];
    this.to = ints[1];
    this.cost = ints[2];
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "Nodes:from=" + from + ".to=" + to + ".cost=" + cost + "\n";
  }

  private static int[] stringToInts(String[] strings) {
    if (strings.length != 3) throw new AssertionError("String array of wrong size. Must be 3");
    int[] ints = new int[strings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
      ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
    }
    return ints;
  }
}
```

---

On reflection the exeption handling can also be achieved just by adding

```
.map(arr-> {if (arr.length != 3) throw new AssertionError("Array size != 3"); return arr;})
```

to the Answer by Hadi J

Answer (score -1):

I don't code java but in python there's a function called list() that converts string to lists and maybe there is one on java too.
or maybe use split(", ") and maybe it will work.

Comment: You did not understood my question.